# Why does NSLineBreakByWordWrapping sometimes not work

Tags: ios, uilabel

I created a UILabel and set lineBreakMode to NSLineBreakByWordWrapping, but sometimes one word is splitted into two lines.

My codes are like belows

```
    _sentenceLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    if (_sentenceLabel.bounds.size.width > self.bounds.size.width - 100) {
       CGSize size = [_info.sentence sizeWithFont:sentenceFont
                                constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width - 100, 1000)];
        _sentenceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

        _sentenceLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        _sentenceLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    }
```

When font name is @"Gill Sans", the line break is not right. (The word "results" is splitted into two  lines)
[image]

When I change to other font, it works again. It is weird.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening with korean characters too, font AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold and others. In an unique label with latin and korean words, for the latin ones the word wrapping is working but it is not for the Korean ones.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation reads:

```
NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
```

Wrapping occurs at word boundaries, **unless the word itself doesn’t fit on a single line**.

Comment: How to handle this case: the word itself doesn’t fit on a single line.